# how to solve Cmake error could not find toolchain file

Tags: android, c++, flutter, cmake, android-ndk

I want to use c++ in my flutter project . To do this I first need to convert my c++ file into a shared library or into a .so file according to android environment. To do so I am using this command:-

```
cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=$ANDROID_NDK/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake -G Ninja -DANDROID_NDK=$ANDROID_NDK -DANDROID_ABI=arm64-v8a -DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-30 -Sandroid -Bbin/android/arm64-v8a
```

But it is continueously showing me this error:-

```
 cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=$ANDROID_NDK/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake -G Ninja -DANDROID_NDK=$ANDROID_NDK -DANDROID_ABI=arm64-v8a -DANDROID_PLATFORM=
android-30 -Sandroid -Bbin/android/arm64-v8a
CMake Warning:
  Ignoring extra path from command line:

   "F:/dart ffi/ffiproject/.toolchain.cmake"


CMake Warning at C:/Users/super/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/25.1.8937393/build/cmake/android-legacy.toolchain.cmake:51 (message):
  Using custom NDK path (ANDROID_NDK is set): F:/dart
  ffi/ffiproject/android/$ANDROID_NDK
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Users/super/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/25.1.8937393/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake:54 (include)
  F:/dart ffi/ffiproject/bin/android/arm64-v8a/CMakeFiles/3.24.1/CMakeSystem.cmake:6 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:5 (project)


CMake Error at C:/Users/super/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/25.1.8937393/build/cmake/android-legacy.toolchain.cmake:64 (file):
  file failed to open for reading (No such file or directory):

    F:/dart ffi/ffiproject/android/$ANDROID_NDK/source.properties
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Users/super/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/25.1.8937393/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake:54 (include)
  F:/dart ffi/ffiproject/bin/android/arm64-v8a/CMakeFiles/3.24.1/CMakeSystem.cmake:6 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:5 (project)


CMake Error at C:/Users/super/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/25.1.8937393/build/cmake/android-legacy.toolchain.cmake:69 (message):
  Failed to parse Android NDK revision: F:/dart
  ffi/ffiproject/android/$ANDROID_NDK/source.properties.

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Users/super/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/25.1.8937393/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake:54 (include)
  F:/dart ffi/ffiproject/bin/android/arm64-v8a/CMakeFiles/3.24.1/CMakeSystem.cmake:6 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:5 (project)


CMake Error at C:/Users/super/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/25.1.8937393/build/cmake/android-legacy.toolchain.cmake:175 (include):
  include could not find requested file:

    F:/dart ffi/ffiproject/android/$ANDROID_NDK/build/cmake/platforms.cmake
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Users/super/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/25.1.8937393/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake:54 (include)
  F:/dart ffi/ffiproject/bin/android/arm64-v8a/CMakeFiles/3.24.1/CMakeSystem.cmake:6 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:5 (project)


-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:5 (project):
  The CMAKE_C_COMPILER:

    F:/dart ffi/ffiproject/android/$ANDROID_NDK/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang.exe

  is not a full path to an existing compiler tool.

  Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
  variable "CC" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_C_COMPILER to the full path to
  the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:5 (project):
  The CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:

    F:/dart ffi/ffiproject/android/$ANDROID_NDK/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang++.exe

  is not a full path to an existing compiler tool.

  Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
  variable "CXX" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to the full path
  to the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "F:/dart ffi/ffiproject/bin/android/arm64-v8a/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "F:/dart ffi/ffiproject/bin/android/arm64-v8a/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

I dont know how to solve it.
Here is my CMakeLists.txt file:-

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
set(CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM "C:/src/ninja-win/ninja.exe" CACHE FILEPATH "" FORCE)
set( CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER g++ )
set( CMAKE_C_COMPILER gcc )
project(ffiproject)
add_library(
    lib
    SHARED
    lib.cpp
)

find_library(
    lib
    log
)
target_link_libraries(
    lib
    ${log_lib}
)
```

Please Help Me

Comment: I am a new student. I dort what $ANDROID_NDK means or how to set it. It will be great if you consider that while you answer my question

Comment: You forgot some hyphens `-` in front of arguments, for instance at`DANDROID_NDK=$ANDROID_NDK`. Arguments are passed to CMake by using `-D <argument_name>=<value>` the space after the `-D` may be omitted.

Comment: @vre I tried this

Comment: And the output of the command must have changed. Please update your question with the current output.

Comment: @vre yes the output has changed let me update it for you

Comment: BTW, the duplicate directories in your toolchain path  `C:/Users/super/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/25.1.8937393/build/cmake/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake`, i.e. `build/cmake/build/cmake` may reveal the real reason for the error. Try `-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=$ANDROID_NDK/android.toolchain.cmake` as argument to CMake.

Comment: @vre now I have updated my question. Please help me

Comment: @vre I tried<code>cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=$ANDROID_NDK/android.toolchain.cmake -G Ninja -DANDROID_NDK=$ANDROID_NDK -DANDROID_ABI=arm64-v8a -DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-30 -Sandroid -Bbin/android/arm64-v8a</code> but it gave me the same error as above

Comment: There is `$ANDROID_NDK` in the output. That means either expression `$ANDROID_NDK` has not been expanded in the command line or it is literal value of `ANDROID_NDK` variable. Do you enter given command line in the terminal or somewhere else? What is value of `ANDROID_NDK` variable? (You may print it with `echo $ANDROID_NDK` command). "I dort what $ANDROID_NDK means or how to set it." - Well, this is the first thing you should learn before building anything for Android. There are plenty number of resources where you could learn it.

Comment: You seem to be working on a windows host. `$` to refer to variables only works in some command lines, e.g. linux bash (and afaik powershell). If you're trying to set up the program from cmd, a different syntax is required. Also doublecheck that the `ANDROID_NDK` environment variable is actually set and contains points to a directory containing the toolchain file in the appropriate path: entering `%ANDROID_NDK%` in the directory path of `explorer` should either take you to the directory or yield an error message.